# Opening Stock, Closing Stock By Date sql Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table with primary key and foreign key (MaterialId)

1. Material Table (Multiple Material)

```
MaterialId   MaterialName   OpeningStock
1            Pen            100
2            Pencil         50
```

2. Material Stock (Multiple Material Entry)

```
MaterialId   PurchaseQty    SalesQty    Date
1            500            0           2016-12-15
1            0              0           2016-12-16
1            300            0           2016-12-17
1            0              400         2016-12-18
1            0              0           2016-12-19
1            0              0           2016-12-20
1            0              400         2016-12-21
1            200            100         2016-12-22
```

Now When I Pass @FromDate and @Todate
I want to output like below:

```
Date         MaterialName   OpeningStock   PurchaseQty   SalesQty    ClosingStock
2016-12-15   Pen            100            500            0           600
2016-12-16   Pen            600            0              0           600
2016-12-17   Pen            600            300            0           900
2016-12-18   Pen            900            0              400         500
2016-12-19   Pen            500            0              0           500
2016-12-20   Pen            500            0              0           500
2016-12-21   Pen            500            0              400         100
2016-12-22   Pen            100            200            100         200
```

**Note :** 
1. If Something is wrong on database tables so, please guide me how to handle this situation.
2. And Also find Current Date Stock From Two Tables

Comment: Have you tried anything so far to solve the problem?

Comment: @KETULSONI please show us your query where you have tried something ?

Comment: 1. Recursive CTE to generate list of dates
2. Cumulative sum

Comment: Why do you think something is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a rolling sum of the various quantity values.  One way to do this is using correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT
    t1.Date,
    mt.MaterialName,
    (SELECT OpeningStock FROM [Material Table] WHERE MaterialId = t1.MaterialId) +
    COALESCE((SELECT SUM(t2.PurchaseQty - t2.SalesQty) FROM [Material Stock] t2
     WHERE t2.Date < t1.Date AND t1.MaterialId = t2.MaterialId), 0) AS OpeningStock,
    t1.PurchaseQty,
    t1.SalesQty,
    (SELECT OpeningStock FROM [Material Table] WHERE MaterialId = t1.MaterialId) +
COALESCE((SELECT SUM(t2.PurchaseQty - t2.SalesQty) FROM [Material Stock] t2
     WHERE t2.Date <= t1.Date AND t1.MaterialId = t2.MaterialId), 0) AS ClosingStock
FROM [Material Stock] t1
INNER JOIN [Material Table] mt
    ON t1.MaterialId = mt.MaterialId
ORDER BY
    mt.MaterialName,
    t1.Date;
```

Note that it is bad table design to be storing the opening stock values in a separate table from the material stock table.  This means the above query would return no pencil records.  A better approach would be to insert a seed record into material stock, for each material, with the amount being the initial stock.

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Thanks, but what about "Pencil" opening stock is 50 quantity.

Comment: You never provided any pencil data, hence nothing appears.  The records you see above are based on the material stock table.  Add some data for pencils and you will get output.

Comment: Ok, but if some of date data is not available then?
Please check - http://rextester.com/NDH6665

Comment: @KETULSONI Your current design is bad, and you should _not_ be storing the initial stocks in a separate table.  Instead, just insert a record into the stock table for each material to seed with the initial stock.  Do you understand?

Answer (score 0):

Simply do as below :

```
SELECT S.DATE, M.MaterialName, M.OpeningStock, S.PurchaseQty, S.SalesQty, SUM((M.OpeningStock+S.PurchaseQty)-S.SalesQty)ClosingStock FROM #TABLE
(
      SELECT * FROM MaterialTABLE
) M

INNER JOIN Material S ON S.MaterialId = M.MaterialId where s.date between @FromDate and @Todate
```