# How to calculate opening and closing stocks for particular date range

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

How to calculate opening and closing stocks for particular date range

I want to calculate opening and closing stocks for items for a provided date range.

I have tables as follows,

```
global_items:
+-----+--------+
| id  | name   |
+-----+--------+
| 1   | item 1 |
+-----+--------+
| 2   | item 2 |
+-----+--------+
| 3   | item 3 |
+-----+--------+
| 4   | item 4 |
+-----+--------+
| ... | ...    |
+-----+--------+

my_items:
+-----+----------------+-----------+
| id  | global_item_id | outlet_id |
+-----+----------------+-----------+
| 1   | 1              | 7         |
+-----+----------------+-----------+
| 2   | 2              | 7         |
+-----+----------------+-----------+
| 3   | 3              | 7         |
+-----+----------------+-----------+
| 4   | 4              | 7         |
+-----+----------------+-----------+
| ... | ...            | ...       |
+-----+----------------+-----------+

my_item_stocks:
+-----+------------+---------+---------------+-----------+---------------+-------+
| id  | my_item_id | size_id | purchase_rate | sale_rate | opening_stock | stock |
+-----+------------+---------+---------------+-----------+---------------+-------+
| 1   | 1          | 10      | 100           | 200       | 0             | 0     |
+-----+------------+---------+---------------+-----------+---------------+-------+
| 2   | 1          | 11      | 100           | 200       | 0             | 5     |
+-----+------------+---------+---------------+-----------+---------------+-------+
| 3   | 2          | 10      | 100           | 200       | 1.05          | 1.05  |
+-----+------------+---------+---------------+-----------+---------------+-------+
| 4   | 3          | 12      | 100           | 200       | 10            | 10    |
+-----+------------+---------+---------------+-----------+---------------+-------+
| ... | ...        | ...     | 100           | 200       | 0             | 1     |
+-----+------------+---------+---------------+-----------+---------------+-------+

sizes:
+-----+--------+----------+
| id  | name   | quantity |
+-----+--------+----------+
| 10  | 750 ml | 750      |
+-----+--------+----------+
| 11  | 500 ml | 500      |
+-----+--------+----------+
| 12  | 350 ml | 350      |
+-----+--------+----------+
| ... | ...    | ...      |
+-----+--------+----------+
```

Then I have sales and purchases tables as follows, adding purchase updates the stock in my_item_stocks and adding sale reduces stock.

```
purchases:
+-----+------------+-----------+
| id  | date       | outlet_id |
+-----+------------+-----------+
| 1   | 2018-07-01 | 7         |
+-----+------------+-----------+
| 2   | 2018-07-10 | 7         |
+-----+------------+-----------+
| 3   | 2018-07-19 | 7         |
+-----+------------+-----------+
| ... | ...        | ...       |
+-----+------------+-----------+

purchase_items:
+-----+-------------+------------+---------+----------+
| id  | purchase_id | my_item_id | size_id | quantity |
+-----+-------------+------------+---------+----------+
| 1   | 1           | 1          | 10      | 2        |
+-----+-------------+------------+---------+----------+
| 2   | 1           | 2          | 11      | 5        |
+-----+-------------+------------+---------+----------+
| 3   | 2           | 2          | 10      | 17       |
+-----+-------------+------------+---------+----------+
| 4   | 3           | 2          | 12      | 15       |
+-----+-------------+------------+---------+----------+
| 5   | 3           | 2          | 12      | 10       |
+-----+-------------+------------+---------+----------+
| ... | ...         | ...        | ...     | ...      |
+-----+-------------+------------+---------+----------+ 

sales:
+-----+------------+-----------+
| id  | date       | outlet_id |
+-----+------------+-----------+
| 1   | 2018-07-01 | 7         |
+-----+------------+-----------+
| 2   | 2018-07-10 | 7         |
+-----+------------+-----------+
| 3   | 2018-07-19 | 7         |
+-----+------------+-----------+
| ... | ...        | ...       |
+-----+------------+-----------+

sale_items:
+-----+-------------+------------+---------+------+
| id  | sale_id | my_item_id | size_id | quantity |
+-----+---------+------------+---------+----------+
| 1   | 1       | 1          | 10      | 1        |
+-----+---------+------------+---------+----------+
| 2   | 1       | 2          | 11      | 2        |
+-----+---------+------------+---------+----------+
| 3   | 2       | 2          | 10      | 10       |
+-----+---------+------------+---------+----------+
| 4   | 3       | 2          | 12      | 5        |
+-----+---------+------------+---------+----------+
| 5   | 3       | 2          | 12      | 2        |
+-----+---------+------------+---------+----------+
| ... | ...     | ...        | ...     | ...      |
+-----+---------+------------+---------+----------+
```

Now for selected date range e.g. from 2018-07-01 to 2018-07-19 I want the output like below,

```
+-----------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
| Item Name |       Opening Stock      |         Purchase         |           Sale           |       Closing Stock      |
+           +--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|           | 750 ml | 500 ml | 350 ml | 750 ml | 500 ml | 350 ml | 750 ml | 500 ml | 350 ml | 750 ml | 500 ml | 350 ml |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Item 1    |        |        |        | 2      | 5      |        | 1      | 2      |        | 3      | 7      |        |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| Item 2    | 1.05   |        |        | 17     |        |        | 10     |        |        | 8.05   |        |        |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| ...       | ...    | ...    | ...    | ...    | ...    | ...    | ...    | ...    | ...    | ...    | ...    | ...    |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I am not sql pro, how can I achieve this? I am confused because of lot of related tables, just want right direction.

I am doing this is laravel so please suggest even if there is any way to achieve this using eloquent.

Models: GlobalItem, MyItem, MyItemStock, Size, Purchase, PurchaseItem, Sale, SaleItem

Many thanks!

Comment: It is possible to generate something similar in sql (well, you cannot have 2 header lines), but that sql cannot be translated into eloquent because it will have to use dynamic sql. This transformation is called pivoting and has been asked and answered here on SO sooo many times. I would produce the output in the application logic, not in sql. Also, pls make an attempt at trying to solve your own question because you are asking us to implement the whole thing from scratch for you. Such questions usually do not fly well here on SO.

Comment: Can you please confirm the logic for calculating closing stock? I'd expect it to be opening_stock + purchases - sales - that works for item 2, but not item 1.

Comment: @Shadow Actually I have tried many different ways using laravel, the main thing is calculating opening and closing stocks dynamically, I think I have to do correlated sub queries as suggested in this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232580/opening-stock-closing-stock-by-date-sql-query) but I am not able to implement that, can you help me?