# Storing opening and closing stock best practice

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables as Inward stock and Outward stock. I'm trying to create day wise opening, inward, outward and closing stock for each items. At any selected day, how do I know what is the closing stock of previous day? Then that becomes opening stock for selected day.  I'm not storing opening and closing stock in separate table since I believe its bad table design.

```
DECLARE @ItemsTable AS TABLE(Item INT,Size INT, Thickness INT, Unit INT);

DECLARE @CalendarItems AS TABLE(Item INT,Size INT,Thickness INT,Unit INT,Date_ DATE);

DECLARE @Inwards AS TABLE(InwardDate DATE, Item INT,Size INT,Thickness INT,Unit INT,Qty DECIMAL(10,2) );

DECLARE @Outwards AS TABLE(OutwardDate DATE, Item INT,Size INT,Thickness INT,Unit INT,Qty DECIMAL(10,2) );

INSERT INTO @ItemsTable
VALUES(1,0,4,19),
    (1,0,4,19),
    (2,0,4,17),
    (2,0,4,17)


     INSERT INTO @CalendarItems
     VALUES(1,0,4,19,'2021-01-14'),
            (1,0,4,19,'2021-01-15'),
            (1,0,4,19,'2021-01-16'),
            (1,0,4,19,'2021-01-17'),
            (2,0,4,17,'2021-01-14'),
            (2,0,4,17,'2021-01-15'),
            (3,0,4,17,'2021-01-16'),
            (4,0,4,17,'2021-01-17')


    INSERT INTO @Inwards
    VALUES('2021-01-14',1,0,4,19,50),
          ('2021-01-15',1,0,4,19,100),
          ('2021-01-14',2,0,4,17,60) 

    INSERT INTO @Outwards
    VALUES('2021-01-15',1,0,4,19,40),
          ('2021-01-16',1,0,4,19,10),
          ('2021-01-16',2,0,4,17,50)
 

    SELECT CT.Date_ [Date], CT.Item, CT.Size, CT.Thickness, CT.Unit, 0.0 Opening, ISNULL(INW.Qty,0) Inward, ISNULL(OW.Qty,0) Outward, 0.0 Closing
    FROM @CalendarItems CT
    LEFT JOIN @Inwards INW ON CT.date_ = INW.InwardDate AND CT.Item = INW.Item AND CT.Size = INW.Size AND CT.Thickness = INW.Thickness AND CT.Unit = INW.Unit 
    LEFT JOIN @Outwards OW ON CT.date_ = OW.OutwardDate AND CT.Item = OW.Item AND CT.Size = OW.Size AND CT.Thickness = OW.Thickness AND CT.Unit = OW.Unit
```

1. How do I get/calculate opening stock for 14-Jan-21?
2. How closing stock of 14-Jan-21 be as opening stock for 15-Jan-21?

Current Result

```
+------------+------+------+-----------+------+---------+--------+---------+---------+
| Date       | Item | Size | Thickness | Unit | Opening | Inward | Outward | Closing |
+------------+------+------+-----------+------+---------+--------+---------+---------+
| 2021-01-14 | 1    | 0    | 4         | 19   | 0       | 50     | 0       | 0       |
+------------+------+------+-----------+------+---------+--------+---------+---------+
| 2021-01-15 | 1    | 0    | 4         | 19   | 0       | 100    | 40      | 0       |
+------------+------+------+-----------+------+---------+--------+---------+---------+
| 2021-01-16 | 1    | 0    | 4         | 19   | 0       | 0      | 10      | 0       |
+------------+------+------+-----------+------+---------+--------+---------+---------+
| 2021-01-17 | 1    | 0    | 4         | 19   | 0       | 0      | 0       | 0       |
+------------+------+------+-----------+------+---------+--------+---------+---------+
| 2021-01-14 | 2    | 0    | 4         | 17   | 0       | 60     | 0       | 0       |
+------------+------+------+-----------+------+---------+--------+---------+---------+
| 2021-01-15 | 2    | 0    | 4         | 17   | 0       | 0      | 0       | 0       |
+------------+------+------+-----------+------+---------+--------+---------+---------+
| 2021-01-16 | 3    | 0    | 4         | 17   | 0       | 0      | 0       | 0       |
+------------+------+------+-----------+------+---------+--------+---------+---------+
| 2021-01-17 | 4    | 0    | 4         | 17   | 0       | 0      | 0       | 0       |
+------------+------+------+-----------+------+---------+--------+---------+---------+
```

Expected Result

```
+------------+------+------+-----------+------+---------+--------+---------+---------+
| Date       | Item | Size | Thickness | Unit | Opening | Inward | Outward | Closing |
+------------+------+------+-----------+------+---------+--------+---------+---------+
| 2021-01-14 | 1    | 0    | 4         | 19   | 0       | 50      | 0       | 50      |
+------------+------+------+-----------+------+---------+--------+---------+---------+
| 2021-01-15 | 1    | 0    | 4         | 19   | 50      | 100    | 40      | 110     |
+------------+------+------+-----------+------+---------+--------+---------+---------+
| 2021-01-16 | 1    | 0    | 4         | 19   | 110     | 0      | 10      | 100     |
+------------+------+------+-----------+------+---------+--------+---------+---------+
| 2021-01-17 | 1    | 0    | 4         | 19   | 100     | 0      | 0       | 100     |
+------------+------+------+-----------+------+---------+--------+---------+---------+
| 2021-01-14 | 2    | 0    | 4         | 17   | 0       | 60     | 0       | 60      |
+------------+------+------+-----------+------+---------+--------+---------+---------+
| 2021-01-15 | 2    | 0    | 4         | 17   | 60      | 0      | 0       | 60      |
+------------+------+------+-----------+------+---------+--------+---------+---------+
| 2021-01-16 | 3    | 0    | 4         | 17   | 0       | 0      | 0       | 0       |
+------------+------+------+-----------+------+---------+--------+---------+---------+
| 2021-01-17 | 4    | 0    | 4         | 17   | 0       | 0      | 0       | 0.0     |
+------------+------+------+-----------+------+---------+--------+---------+---------+
```

Note that when item changes opening stock is set to 0

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Why store closing *and* opening stock, they will be the same thing?

Comment: Agree, updated the image. Thanks!

Comment: @Charlieface - Currently I',m not storing opening or closing anywhere. Trying to calculate from inward and outward.

Comment: If you provide your DDL+DML i.e. declaring `CalendarItems ` and inserting into, its a lot easier for us to assist you.

Comment: Re framed the question and added more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feed your given query to another query with windowing sum functions:

1. Opening is `Sum(Inward) Over (partition by ItemId, SizeId, ThicknessId, UnitId Order By Date) - Sum(Outward) Over (partition by ItemId, SizeId, ThicknessId, UnitId Order By Date) - Inward + Outward`
2. Closing is `Sum(Inward) Over (partition by ItemId, SizeId, ThicknessId, UnitId Order By Date) - Sum(Outward) Over (partition by ItemId, SizeId, ThicknessId, UnitId Order By Date)`

So,

```
Select Date,ItemId, SizeId, ThicknessId, UnitId,
       Sum(Inward) Over (partition by ItemId, SizeId, ThicknessId, UnitId Order By Date)
     - Sum(Outward) Over (partition by ItemId, SizeId, ThicknessId, UnitId Order By Date)
     - Inward + Outward as Opening, Inward, Outward,
       Sum(Inward) Over (partition by ItemId, SizeId, ThicknessId, UnitId Order By Date)
     - Sum(Outward) Over (partition by ItemId, SizeId, ThicknessId, UnitId Order By Date)
     As Closing
From (
      SELECT CT.Date_ [Date], CT.Item, CT.Size, CT.Thickness, CT.Unit, 0.0 Opening, ISNULL(INW.Qty,0) Inward, ISNULL(OW.Qty,0) Outward, 0.0 Closing
      FROM @CalendarItems CT
           LEFT JOIN @Inwards INW ON CT.date_ = INW.InwardDate AND CT.Item = INW.Item AND CT.Size = INW.Size AND CT.Thickness = INW.Thickness AND CT.Unit = INW.Unit 
           LEFT JOIN @Outwards OW ON CT.date_ = OW.OutwardDate AND CT.Item = OW.Item AND CT.Size = OW.Size AND CT.Thickness = OW.Thickness AND CT.Unit = OW.Unit
      )
Order By ItemId, SizeId, ThicknessId, UnitId, Date
```

Note that this does not account for opening balance from prior time periods - it always begins with zero opening.

Comment: Fantastic! You made my day! I'm planning to maintain opening and closing stock of each item on each day in separate table in order to get opening balance from prior time period. Is there any other better way to get prior opening balance instead of storing data?

Comment: Technically, you can also move those windowing functions right into your original query and not bother with the outer query at all, but I wanted to show how close you were already with our original query.

Comment: It is a better practice to save snapshots of balance from time to time than to recreate from day zero.  This allows for people to take physical inventory and fix mistakes, losses, etc. into a table and have all calculations going forward to be based on a corrected number.

Comment: Totally agree with you. I was referring to similar question and @Tim Biegeleisen answer note [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232580/opening-stock-closing-stock-by-date-sql-query) . Didn't get through why it says it bad table design. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: From a purely theoretical view adding records to your table is more compact code and easier to maintain, and *theoretically* you could go into your tables and adjust Inward & Outward to compensate for loss, theft, and error.  But I'm disagreeing in this case - mostly it's too hard after performing a physical inventory count to figure out where you went wrong.  Better to have a *physical* record of that inventory event in your DB.  It's a better reflection of reality.